# Adding data into hashmap if the orders are multiple (Java)

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I am trying to add **key (restaurant_id)** and **value (order_id)** in **HashMap**. For single order from a restaurant, I am able to add the **restaurant_id** and **order_id** in **HashMap** pretty easily.

I am facing bit difficulty when it comes to orders from a multiple restaurants.

Here is code which provides **restaurant ids**

```
//Get multiple restaurant ids
  for(int i = 0; i < Utils.cart_map.size(); i++)
  {
        RestaurantModel restaurant = Utils.cart_restaurants.get(i);        
        String restaurantId = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(restaurant.getId()));
  }
```

This above for loop gives **restaurant_ids** which are presented in the cart.

This below code which fetches **Order ids**

```
// get multiple order ids
for (int j = 0; j < orders.length(); j++)
{
    order_id = orders.getString(j);
    ordersHashMap.put(restaurantId, order_id);
}
```

Here is the full code:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < Utils.cart_map.size(); i++)
 {
      RestaurantModel restaurant = Utils.cart_restaurants.get(i); 
      String restaurantId = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(restaurant.getId()));
       for (int j = 0; j < orders.length(); j++)
       {
             order_id = orders.getString(j);

             ordersHashMap.put(restaurantId, order_id);
       }
}
```

For example: **restaurant_ids** are **41 and 42**. and the **order ids** for **41 is 10001** and **42 is 10002**. When i run above code, it gives me saves same order_ids for each restaurant. 
Here is the output:

```
"42" -> "10001"
"41" -> "10001"
```

The output should be like this.

```
"42" -> "10001"
"41" -> "10002"
```

I am not able to find out what I am missing out here.

Help would be appreciated

Comment: It looks like `orders` is just a collection of `Strings` - how is it defined that any `order` belongs to a certain restaurant?   If there is such definition then you should check it in your loop, otherwise all elements in `ordersHashMap` will be updated

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yeah that makes sense. Whats the best way to achieve this? I am getting orders from api.

Comment: Is there a way to get orders for a single Restaurant? If so then you would have some control.  Or does the data returned in fact contain the `restaurantId` ?

Comment: I believe this line for (int j = 0; j < orders.length(); j++) is what serving same order_ids for each restaurant. While getting order_ids using api, it is good to get restaurant_id as well for that order. Looks like this will solve my problem

Comment: Put a log and see the values of   restaurantId and  order_id in   ordersHashMap.put(restaurantId, order_id); and see while inserting what values are getting assigned.  If suppose from your API you are getting different values for same key then it will update the previous inserted value as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `ArrayList` and added `restaurant_ids` in that. 
Here is the complete code.

```
ArrayList<String> restList = new ArrayList<String>();
String restaurantId = null;

//Get multiple restaurant ids
for(int i = 0; i < Utils.cart_map.size(); i++) {

    RestaurantModel restaurant = Utils.cart_restaurants.get(i); // Restaurants details which are presented in cart
    restaurantId = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(restaurant.getId()));

    restList.add(restaurantId);
}

// get multiple order ids
for (int j = 0; j < orders.length(); j++) {

    String rest_id = restList.get(j);
    order_id = orders.getString(j);

    ordersHashMap.put(rest_id, order_id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are parsing the same orders for all restaurants, so all orders for all restaurants. Not just orders for specific restaurant. Btw. your code will work only if there is just one order for one restaurant. Because in a Map you can assign just one value to a key.